# Understanding Automatic Reference Counting in Simple Code Example

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

My knowledge of ARC is limited, so I am wanting to learn more about it. Take this simple example code for instance:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [[self window] setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [[self window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

My question is this: what happens to rootViewController throughout the scope of the method? My intuition is this:

1. I alloc and init a UIViewController, so I own the object, and the retainCount of rootViewController is 1.
2. When setRootViewController gets invoked, the retainCount of rootViewController gets incremented, so self.window points to it strongly. The retainCount is now 2.
3. When didFinishLaunchingWithOptions returns, I am no longer relevant, so my contract with rootViewController has ended. After the method returns, the retainCount gets decremented because I have gone out of scope. The retainCount is 1, with self.window owning the rootViewController.

Comment: That sounds right. Is `self.window` a strong reference?

Comment: Yes, `self.window` is a strong property.

Comment: I think this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1 can help you with understanding what's going on under ARC.

Comment: Your intuition sounds exactly right.

Comment: Almost;  the absolute value of the retain counts is coincidental. Think of 'em entirely as deltas;  +alloc == +1.  Nil'ing out the reference (or letting it fall out of scope) is -1, etc... and in ARC, you really should not have to care beyond retain cycles.